# How can I change the executing order of two or more advice annotated by the same annotation such as @Around in AspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

Here's my code:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
public void cutPointToken() {}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
public void cutPointEmptyParam() {}

@Around("cutPointToken()")
public Object authenticateToken(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOGGER.info("authenticate -- start --");
    ...
    Object o = joinPoint.proceed();
    LOGGER.info("authenticate -- end --");
    return o;
}

@Around("cutPointEmptyParam()")
public Object checkParameter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOGGER.info("check param -- start --");
    ...
    Object o = joinPoint.proceed();
    LOGGER.info("check param -- end --");
    return o;
}
```

I got:

```
authenticate -- start --
check param -- start --
...
check param -- end --
authenticate -- end --
```

Expected:

```
check param -- start --
authenticate -- start --
...
authenticate -- end --
check param -- end --
```

How can I change the executing order of those two methods?

Tried `@Order` annotation, `@Order(1)` on the `checkParameter` method, and `@Order(2)` on the other, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show how you're applying your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of using `@Order` annotation is correct, however, place it on the class level as the documentation [7.2.4.7 Advice ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) states.

> This is done in the normal Spring way by either implementing the org.springframework.core. Ordered interface in the aspect class or annotating it with the Order annotation.

The placement on the methods annotated with `@Aspect` will not work since it is not registered as a bean. Find `@Order` annotation in [1.9.2. @Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation) section.

> The `@Order` annotation may be declared at target class level but also on `@Bean` methods...

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class CheckParameterAspect {

    @Around("cutPointEmptyParam()")
    public Object checkParameter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //...
    }
}

@Aspect
@Order(2)
public class AuthenticateTokenAspect {

    @Around("cutPointToken()")
    public Object authenticateToken(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //...
    }
}
```

Edit: The ordering from `0` seems to be possible.